# Python 3 how to properly return a value in function for later use

Tags: python

I'm a python newbie. I created a calculator program that will accept 2 number and a type of operation from user. I already have a working code for this but I want to further simplify the code by exploring and using function.
Here's the portion of the code:

```
def addition(num1,num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    print('The sum is ', sum)
def subtraction(num1,num2):
    sub = num1 - num2
    print('The difference is ', sub)
def inputNumber():
    num1 = float(input('Enter the first number: '))
    num2 = float(input('Enter the second number: '))
    return num1,num2
print('Enter the corresponding number to perform the operation:\n')
print('1 - addition')
print('2 - subtraction')
print('q - quit')
while True:
    try:
        operation = input('Select operation > ').lower()
    if operation == 'q':
        break
    elif operation == '1':
        addition(inputNumber())
    elif operation == '2':
        subtraction(inputNumber())
    else:
        print('Not valid. Try again.')
except:
    print('Invalid!')
```

My problem is after entering 2 numbers it doesn't perform the operation. I think the problem is the 2 input values didn't return properly.

Thanks

Comment: I think its better to give like this : `n,p = inputNumber()`...
`subtraction(n,p)`

Comment: You are printing at the end of your function, not returning.

Comment: try unpack the return value of `inputNumber()` which is a tuple. `addition(*inputNumber())`

Comment: Thanks guys. Now i learn that return I made is a tuple which is basically a "list" and use index to assign its value to other parts of the code. This helps a lot. I understand now how return works. I wasted so many hours debugging and trying different forms of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. `inputNumber` function is returning a single tuple of both your float.

```
def addition(num):    #--->Update
    sum = num[0] + num[1]     #--->using index to get first and second number.
    print('The sum is ', sum)
def subtraction(num):    #--->Update
    sub = num[0] - num[1]      #--->using index to get first and second number.

    print('The difference is ', sub)
def inputNumber():
    num1 = float(input('Enter the first number: '))
    num2 = float(input('Enter the second number: '))
    return num1,num2                 #-----> Returns a tuple. EX: (3.0, 4.0)
print('Enter the corresponding number to perform the operation:\n')
print('1 - addition')
print('2 - subtraction')
print('q - quit')
while True:
    try:
        operation = input('Select operation > ').lower()
        if operation == 'q':
            break
        elif operation == '1':
            addition(inputNumber())
        elif operation == '2':
            subtraction(inputNumber())
        else:
            print('Not valid. Try again.')
    except Exception, e:
        print('Invalid!', e)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now, I see now the problem, the input function is returning only the first value. I learn now that using index will return the two values. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
def addition((num1,num2)):
    sum = num1 + num2
    print('The sum is ', sum)
def subtraction((num1,num2)):
    sub = num1 - num2
    print('The difference is ', sub)
def inputNumber():
    num1 = float(raw_input('Enter the first number: '))
    num2 = float(raw_input('Enter the second number: '))
    return num1,num2
print('Enter the corresponding number to perform the operation:\n')
print('1 - addition')
print('2 - subtraction')
print('q - quit')
while True:
    try:
        operation = raw_input('Select operation > ').lower()
        if operation == 'q':
            break
        elif operation == '1':
            import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
            addition(inputNumber())
        elif operation == '2':
            subtraction(inputNumber())
        else:
            print('Not valid. Try again.')
    except:
        print('Invalid!')
```

1. Use `raw_input` to take inputs from user containing `string` as well as `int` (applicable for python 2 only)
2. Check `Try except` indentation.
3. `return` keyword returns in a tuple, so modify addition and subtraction.

Comment: 1. I'm using python 3, anyway thanks for this.
2. Try-except is working fine, the problem is the input values not returning properly.
3. This solves my problem, as Rakesh pointed out that my return returns a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your functions expect two inputs, but get a tuple (that is what a function return when you use `return foo, bar`)

you can expand the tuple using an astrix like this (also fixed indentation issue):

```
def addition(num1,num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    print('The sum is ', sum)
def subtraction(num1,num2):
    sub = num1 - num2
    print('The difference is ', sub)
def inputNumber():
    num1 = float(input('Enter the first number: '))
    num2 = float(input('Enter the second number: '))
    return num1,num2
print('Enter the corresponding number to perform the operation:\n')
print('1 - addition')
print('2 - subtraction')
print('q - quit')
while True:
    try:
        operation = input('Select operation > ').lower()
        if operation == 'q':
            break
        elif operation == '1':
            addition(*inputNumber())
        elif operation == '2':
            subtraction(*inputNumber())
        else:
            print('Not valid. Try again.')
    except:
        print('Invalid!')
```

Comment: This also works. Thanks. @shayelk
I never knew putting an asterisk will expand the tuple.
I'll take note this.